# duplicate cookies in IE 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, http, cookies

I'm using (client side) cookies (in javascript) to store user selected key/value pairs from one session to the next and from page to page. It seems that Chrome, Safari and Firefox understand that a key can have only one value, but IE takes a different view.
For example:
I have a feature ("viewMode")that can take one of four user-selectable values:-2, -1, 0 or 1. 
When I set the cookie, I give it an expiry date of today + 100 days.

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, expireDays) {
    expireDays *= 1;
    var expireDate = new Date();
    expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + expireDays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((expireDays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + expireDate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value; 
}
```

The default value is 0. When the user selects value, say 1, generating a call

```
setCookie("viewMode", 1, 100);
```

IE stores BOTH values, but the others understand the concept that the key has been overwritten.
Here's the cookie component of the HTTP GET for the next load:

```
Cookie: dispText=FileName; viewMode=0; MultiTrack=0; showClouds=0; smokeTrailLength=256; IGCAltSource=0; HideTracks=0; ColorSpeed=1; showCompass=0; viewMode=1; chosenDirectoryPath=C%3A%5CAlan%5CSTarTraXdata%5CTestTracks; IGCAltSource=1; showCockpitInstruments=0; showJavaOPenPopup=0; dispText=None; smokeTrailLength=-1; PHPSESSID=d96b0827725b1e6e313dcdfddfaed0a0
```

As you can see, the cookie "viewMode" appears twice, once as viewMode=0 and once as viewMode = 1.
So... is a cookie really a key/value pair and IE has it wrong, or what?
I've seen posts that suggest that cookies are a key/value/date triple, but that doesn't seem supported elsewhere and I can't find the spec in the W3C doco.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer, but my problem is resolved with a work-around!
I had even tried to delete the viewMode cookie by

```
document.cookie="viewMode =; expires=15/02/2003 00:00:00";
```

without any success.

In a fit of exasperation, I **deleted all my IE cookies** and now everything works just fine!

Seems that the "viewMode=1" cookie was some sort of monster ("Cookie Monster" get it Ha Ha) that didn't respond to being changed or deleted.
Now my page is happily updating the viewMode cookie as expected.

So I have a work-around, but I'd still love to know what's really happening.